# Will Android App with no launcher ever receive FCM messages?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Looking at the setup for FCM Messaging in Android.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client

It states:

> On initial startup of your app, the FCM SDK generates a registration token for the client app instance.

Sounds good, except I don't know when the initial startup of the app will be.
If the app has no launcher activity, it can't be started by the user.
Furthermore, the app is preinstalled by an OEM or carrier.
So, will it ever get a registration token? Will it ever get an FCM message?

> The registration token may change when:
>
> - The app is restored on a new device
> - The user uninstalls/reinstall the app
> - The user clears app data.

Conspicuously, this does not mention when app is installed or when app is preinstalled as a time when a token is generated.
It is then tempting to register for a boot completed event.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.test.example" >
...
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

...

<application>
    ...

    <receiver android:name="com.test.example.MyCustomBroadcastReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
            <!-- REGISTER TO RECEIVE BOOT_COMPLETED EVENTS -->
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

However, based on dozens of questions here, it is very unclear whether an app will ever receive this event if it has never been launched. And if it has no launcher...

Comment: "So, will it ever get a registration token?" -- FCM code in the FCM SDK that is in your app will need to request and store the token. If you execute that code at a point when there is a usable Internet connection that can get to Google's servers, you will get a token. Otherwise, you will not. "this does not mention when app is installed" -- nothing is run when an app is installed, since Android 3.1, for security reasons. Something has to use an explicit `Intent` to start one of the app's components. Typically, this is via the user launching your launcher activity.

Comment: Yes, typically. Since it doesn't have a launcher. I'd likely have to launch an explicit intent from another app to make sure it wakes up.

Comment: Yeah, your scenario is unusual. Whoever is building the firmware that will contain your app may have some suggestions as to how to proceed. Or, you might try some other forums that are more tied into custom firmware builds (e.g., XDA's). Stack Overflow mostly is for conventional apps, installed by users, rather than pre-installed ones.